# WITH ROLLUP in MySql Repeats column when filling in for NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql (5.7+) query in which I'm trying to substitute for `NULL`, but it repeats the same columns data and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here. Is it just syntax?

Query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(t1.ID, '') AS 'ID',
    CASE WHEN t1.ID IS NULL
        THEN 'Totals' 
    ELSE t1.description 
        END AS 'Desc', 
    COUNT(t2.another_int) AS 'Count',
    COUNT(t2.counter) AS 'Another count'
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.other_id 
    AND t2.name = 'aname' 
GROUP BY t1.ID WITH ROLLUP;
```

I expect:

```
+----+-------+-------+---------------+
| ID | Desc  | Count | Another Count |
+------------+-------+---------------+
|  1 | Desc1 | 1     |     2         |
|  2 | Desc2 | 5     |     0         |
|  2 | Desc3 | 0     |     1         |
|    | Totals| 6     |     3         |
+----+-------+-------+---------------+
```

I'm getting:

```
+----+-------+-------+---------------+
| ID | Desc  | Count | Another Count |
+------------+-------+---------------+
|  1 | Desc3 | 1     |     2         |   
|  2 | Desc3 | 5     |     0         |       
|  2 | Desc3 | 0     |     1         |
|    | Desc3 | 6     |     3         |
+----+-------+-------+---------------+
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong here, but I'm struggling to find the correct syntax.  Also, making the `GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.desc` just puts a `NULL` on every `t1.description` row. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Pretty sure you just need to add T1.description to your group by.  mySQL group by extension is free to choose any value from T1.Description otherwise.

Comment: That doesn't work either.  I updated above as well.